# Widgets are not displayed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm currently doing a tutorial on how to create GUI apps from a book called "Modern PyQt" by Joshua Willman and I'm stuck right out of the gate:

I've copy pasted a basic code snippet from the book and tried to tweak it bit by bit instead of reading a bunch of text without any practical trial and error. I can display a window and adjust it's size and properties, but when I try to attach other widgets to the main window, they just don't show up.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
# First practical example from the book: Pomodoro time manager
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Pomodoro(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self): # Create default constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.initializeUI()
    
    def initializeUI(self):
        """Initialize the window and display its contents to the screen."""
        self.setGeometry(int((SCREEN_WIDTH-WINDOW_WIDTH)/2),int((SCREEN_HEIGHT-WINDOW_HEIGHT)/2),WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT) # x,y,w,h
        self.setWindowTitle('Bortism')
        # self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Borticon.png"))
        self.button1 = QPushButton()
        self.button1.setText('Button')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1000,600
    SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = app.desktop().screenGeometry().getRect()
    window = Pomodoro()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That book is not intended for beginners. In the section **Who Should Read This Book** it states: "This guide is intended for intermediate-level Python programmers or above with experience developing and coding GUIs". I would therefore strongly urge you to at least work your way through a basic PyQt tutorial before going any further. You will get much more out of your book if you do that first. Here's a couple for you to try: (1) [RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/), (2) [ZetCode](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/).

Comment: "tried to tweak it bit by bit instead of reading a bunch of text" -> I can understand the curiosity of trying things to see their result (which is a good thing), but if you are reading a book, you cannot just "jump to conclusions" because you don't want to read "a bunch of text" without expecting something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a widget to be shown as part of another then the requirement is that the first is the child of the second. This can be done by passing the parent or by using a layout (which is also passed to it by the parent). So in your case you must change to:

```py
self.button1 = QPushButton(self)
```

Comment: So when creating the instance of a class (in this case a QPushButton widget) it isn't the "self" in self.button1 part that attaches the widget to the Pomodoro class as a child, but the "self" in QPushbutton(self)? I thought when you put the name of a class in the brackets while creating it, it just makes it inherit the methods and static variables of that class: Example: DataStorage(dict) is a class that now has all the methods and variables of a python dictionary.

Comment: @J.Doe self.foo just makes the scope of the object assigned to self.foo that of the class. self.foo does not make that object a child of the class, please read your notes on OOP. On the other hand, the similarity for one widget to be part of another is not the same relationship of the classes based on inheritance

Comment: ah so it's just good practice to do self.button1, just in case there's a global variable elsewhere in the script called button1 and QPushButton(self) is implicit for QPushButton(parent=self)?

Comment: @J.Doe 1) Avoid global variables, if there is another option then choose that option. 2) Yes.